# notice method in view after scaffolding?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I did a scaffolding and all of a sudden I see this in my controller:

```
    format.html { redirect_to @club, notice: 'Club was successfully updated.' }
```

And in my view I see this:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
```

Is this notice method in the view, the same than doing flash[:notice]? If so, where is this method defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`notice` is a convenience method for `flash[:notice]`.

See the documentation here:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash/FlashHash.html#method-i-notice

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, `alert` and `notice` are already preregistered flash types.

You can add custom types if you wish by adding to your controller:

```
add_flash_types :my_custom_type, :my_another_flash_type
```